# Ansible jinja2 - how to format and flatten cartesian product?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Imagine I have the following inventory

```
[myservers]
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.6
```

And in my vars file, the following:

```
interesting_things:
  - name: alice
    port: 8080
  - name: bob
    port: 8181
```

How can I produce the following result?

```
127.0.0.1[8080],127.0.0.1[8181],192.168.0.6[8080],192.168.0.6[8181]
```

I tried getting the cartesian product, but came unstuck:

```
debug: msg="{{ lookup('cartesian', groups['myservers'], interesting_things | map(attribute='port')) }}"
```

This gave me the following, but I can't work out how to go any further.

```
{
    "msg": [
        [
            "127.0.0.1",
            8080
        ],
        [
            "127.0.0.1",
            8181
        ],
        [
            "192.168.0.6",
            8080
        ],
        [
            "192.168.0.6",
            8181
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what you already have:

```
- name:
  set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ my_list|default([]) + [my_element] }}"
  vars:
    my_element: "{{ item[0] }}[{{ item[1] }}]"
  with_items:
    - "{{ lookup('cartesian', groups['myservers'], interesting_things | map(attribute='port')) }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_list|join(',') }}"
```

Result:

```
"msg": "127.0.0.1[8080],127.0.0.1[8181],192.168.0.6[8080],192.168.0.6[8181]"
```

Comment: Amazing.  I pity the poor soul that's going to support this playbook in future.